# How many bonus priest spells do you get for high Intuition?

Tags: druid, cleric, adnd-2e, optional-rules

How exactly do the Bonus Spells granted by the Wisdom/Intuition subability work in 2E Skills & Powers?

For example, at Intuition 17, a priest has "3rd" bonus spells, and at Intuition 18, "4th" bonus spells, per Table 10:

```
-------------------------------
Intuition    Bonus      % Spell
  Score      Spells     Failure
-------------------------------
   ...        ...         ...
    17        3rd         0%
    18        4th         0%
   ...        ...      (etc.)
-------------------------------
```

Does this mean a priest with 18 Intuition gets one extra 4th level spell, in addition to the standard progression listed in Table 34?  Does s/he also get the bonuses granted for "lesser" Intuition scores (i.e., 2 extra 1st level spells, 2 extra 2nd level spells and an extra 3rd level spell)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you get all the bonus spells for your Intuition score and below. Pages 18–19, emphasis mine:

> **Bonus Spells:** This is the number of additional spells that priest characters receive, according to their Intuition scores. Note that **the extra spells are cumulative**, and the priest can cast only those spells allowed by his experience level.

So priest with 18 Intuition would get two 1st, two 2nd, one 3rd, and one 4th level bonus spells (once they could cast those levels of spells in the first place).